# generate image from latent vector

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

i am  interested and studying GAN models for generating  images from latent  random vectors,my question is  following : how can i define universal  function which takes argument of latent vector and  desired dimension and returns  image with given dimension?

for instance if we check following tutorial :[GAN for mnist](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-generative-adversarial-network-for-an-mnist-handwritten-digits-from-scratch-in-keras/), we can see that following code :

```
  def define_generator(latent_dim):
            model = Sequential()
            # foundation for 7x7 image
            n_nodes = 128 * 7 * 7
            model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=latent_dim))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
            # upsample to 14x14
            model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            # upsample to 28x28
            model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
            model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
            model.add(Conv2D(1, (7,7), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
            return model
```

this will return image with size of (28,28,1) but what about if i want image by n xn ?

Comment: Change the function signature to define_generator(latent_dim, n). Then change n_nodes to 128 * (n/4) * (n/4)